# Dropdown Menu covered by flexslider in Android (4.1) browser

Tags: jquery, css

I have a responsive WordPress set up for my site and for some reason on Android when I drilldown the menu it's covered by the flexslider. It's not doing this in the iOS Safari or Chrome browsers. Nor is it happening on the desktop before the css media queries kick in for the smaller resolutions. Any clue what could be causing it? My Z-indexes are set properly. Let me know if you need any of my code, here's the site:

http://wp.oursaviorschurch.com

EDIT: I've made a discovery that this is ONLY on 4.1 Jelly Bean. I tested a device running ICS and it worked fine. Also tried it on third party browsers on my Jelly Bean device and it worked properly...this is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across something very similar before, it's all because the position property of the visible slide (in the woo-slider) is set using relative, change this to absolute and the slider will still work but any elements higher up in the DOM that use absolute positioning will now be able to appear in front providing the z-index are correct as yours are.

1. Modify the `flexslider.css` file at line number 48, setting the `'.slides'` container to match the height of the child slides at `350px`.
2. Modify the `jquery-flexslider-min.js` file replacing:

   ```
   slider.slides.css({
       "width": "100%", 
       "float": "left", 
       "marginRight": "-100%", 
       "position": "relative"
   });
   ```

   with:

   ```
   slider.slides.css({
       "width": "100%", 
       "float": "left", 
       "marginRight": "-100%", 
       "position": "absolute"
   });
   ```

As I don't have an Android device I can't test this before submitting my answer. This has only been tested by modifying your markup via the Chrome inspector, but it should work the same in all other major desktop and mobile browsers currently in use. Let me know if doesn't.